# Does Websphere 7.0 support JAX-WS 2.1?

Tags: websphere, jax-ws

I have a web application that use a JAX-WS 2.1 in order to create a client .. when running the application on Webshpere 2.1 I keep getting NoDefClassFoundError on XMLStreamBuffer. I googled the error but I couldn't find anything helpful. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

From the [WAS 7 Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/cwbs_jaxws.html):

> WebSphere® Application Server Version 7.0 supports the JAX-WS 2.1 specification.

Since there is no type called `XMLStreamBuffer` in the [Java 6 SE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), [Java EE 5](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/) or [JAX-WS 2.1](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1/docs/api/index.html) public APIs you are perhaps importing a type from another implementation - either directly or via some generated code.